# I having problem with my searching function C++

Tags: c++

i'am begginner in C++, i want to ask question about what's wrong about my coding, when i doing my work then found out problem i can't solve in searching function, there's no error notice or anything from visual studio but my function still didn't work,
sorry for my bad english.

here is my full code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#define MAX 5

using namespace std;

struct College {
    int nim;
    string name;
}mahasiswa;
struct queue {

    College college[MAX];
    int start,end = - 1;
}antrean;
void init() {
    antrean.start= -1;
    antrean.end = -1;
}

bool full() {
    if (antrean.end== MAX - 1) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

bool empty() {
    if (antrean.end== -1) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

void tampilData() {
    int i;
    if (!empty()) {
        for (i = antrean.start; i < antrean.end; i++)
        {
            cout<<antrean.college[i].nim<<" | ";
            cout << antrean.college[i].name << " | ";
            cout << "\n";
        }
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}

void inQueue() {
    tampilData();
    int elemennim;
    string elemenname;
    
    if (!full()) {
        cout << "Input your NIM : ";
        cin >> elemennim;
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "Input your name: ";
        cin >> elemenname;
        cout << "\n";

        cout << "Succefully\n";
        antrean.college[antrean.end].nim = elemennim;
        antrean.college[antrean.end].name = elemenname;
        antrean.end++;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Queue Penuh\n";
    }
}
```

and this the error function i cant solve,

```
void searching(int key) {
for (int i = 0; i <= antrean.start; i++)
{
    if (key == antrean.college[i].nim) {
        cout << "Element found  in index " << i;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Element not found\n";
    }
    cout << antrean.college[i].nim;
}
    
}

int main() {
    int choice, elemen;
    init();
    cout << "Demo Queue dengan Linear Array" << endl;
    do {
        tampilData();
        cout << "\nMenu Utama\n";
        cout << "==============\n";
        cout << "[1] Init \n[2] InQueue \n[3] Searching \n[4] out \n";
        cout << "==============\n";
        cout << "\nMasukkan pilihan: "; cin >> choice;
        cout << "==============\n";
        
        switch (choice) {
        case 1: init(); break;
        case 2: inQueue(); break;
        case 3: cout << "masukkan NIM yang ingin dicari \n";
            cin >> choice;
            searching(choice); break;

    } while (choice != 0);
    
    return 0;
}
```

please help me, thank you very much

Comment: are you coming from C, or are you using a C book to learn C++ ? There isn't much C++ in your code but it could benefit from actually using C++

Comment: Please be more specific than "didn't work". What was supposed to happen but didn't, or wasn't supposed to happen but did?

Comment: You never change `antrean.start` after `init()`, so your loop in `searching` encounters condition `0 <= -1`, which is `false`, and your loop never runs. Did you mean `for (int i = 0; i <= antrean.end; i++)` instead?

Comment: `int start,end = - 1;` is `int start; int end = -1;` and I didnt find where you initialize `start` but you are using the value, which is undefined behavior. Constructors are supposed to initialize members.

Comment: Your code prints `"Element not found\n"` for every element that isn't what you're looking for. You don't know that the element wasn't found until after the loop.